# Setting up filters with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to do something, which I think should be fairly simple, but can't figure out the correct answer. In the **view** below, I want be able to choose from one of the following engineering disciplines, hit the `Filter` button. When the page reloads, the loop in the view would only add markers that fell under a the specified filter, or in the case where no filter was applied, they would all show.

I have never done any filtering before in rails and because of this, I am completely lost. I also feel like I need to alter my routes.rb file to accommodate for the extra routes that the filter would cause.

**Controller**

```
class DynamicPagesController < ApplicationController
  def map
    @fields = ['Software Engineering',
        'Mechanical Engineering', 
        'Electrical Engineering',
        'Aerospace Engineering',
        'Civil Engineering',
        'Chemical Engineering',
        'Architectural Engineering']
  end
end
```

**View**

```
<%= select(:primary_field, :id, @fields) %>
<%= button_to "Filter", map_path, :method => :get, class: "btn btn-primary" %>

...

for (var i = 0; i < companies.length; i++){
    markers.addLayer(new L.Marker([companies[i].latitude, companies[i].longitude]).bindPopup(companies[i].popup, { maxHeight:150 }).openPopup());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you can check if the filter param is present and filter depending on the value:

```
if params[:filter].present?
    # This will apply the filter
    Model.where(attribute: params[:filter])
else
    # This will return all records
    Model.all
end
```

And since you have a standard select when no option is selected it will return all records. If the blank option does not appear by default you can force it by adding `allow_blank: true` to your select field:

```
select(:primary_field, :id, @fields, allow_blank: true)
```